# How can I install a package using `pip` on python 3.x instead of 2.7?

Tags: python-3.x

I have python2.7 and python3.5 on mac. I am using python3 and change it as default (`alias python=python3`)

With instruction, I install twilio by `pip install twilio`, but it shows

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twilio in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio-5.4.0-py2.7.egg
```

How can I install twilio on python3 packages so that I can import twilio on python3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now and I am reading your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pip` you are referring to your installation of Python 2.x. The alias you mentioned only affects the call to the REPL, so that you can call `python3` by typing `python`.

You need to use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install twilio --upgrade
```

Just add `--upgrade` in case it is [already installed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python).